# Seaborn Plot including different distributions of the same data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn

I wish to create a `seaborn` `pointplot` to display the full data distribution in a column, alongside the distribution of the lowest 25% of values, and the distribution of the highest 25% of values, and all side by side (on the x axis).
My attempt so far provides me with the values, but they are displayed on the same part of the x-axis only and not spread out from left to right on the graph, and with no obvious way to label the points from x-ticks (which I would prefer , rather than via a legend).

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df1 = df[(df.total_bill < df.total_bill.quantile(.25))]
df2 = df[(df.total_bill > df.total_bill.quantile(.75))]

sns.pointplot(y=df['total_bill'], data=df, color='red')
sns.pointplot(y=df1['total_bill'], data=df1, color='green')
sns.pointplot(y=df2['total_bill'], data=df2, color='blue')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `.join()` the new distributions to your existing `df` and then `.plot()` using wide format:

```
lower, upper = df.total_bill.quantile([.25, .75]).values.tolist()
df = df.join(df.loc[df.total_bill < lower, 'total_bill'], rsuffix='_lower')
df = df.join(df.loc[df.total_bill > upper, 'total_bill'], rsuffix='_upper')
sns.pointplot(data=df.loc[:, [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('total')]])
```

to get:

[image]

If you wanted to add groups, you could simply use `.unstack()` to get to `long` format:

```
df = df.loc[:, ['total_bill', 'total_bill_upper', 'total_bill_lower']].unstack().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1).dropna()
df.columns = ['grp', 'val']
```

to get:

```
sns.pointplot(x='grp', y='val', hue='grp', data=df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would think along the lines of adding a "group" and then plot as a single DataFrame.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df = df.append(df)

df.loc[(df.total_bill < df.total_bill.quantile(.25)),'group'] = 'L'
df.loc[(df.total_bill > df.total_bill.quantile(.75)),'group'] = 'H'
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.loc[len(df)/2:,'group'] = 'all'

sns.pointplot(data = df,
              y='total_bill',
              x='group',
              hue='group',
              linestyles='')
```

[image: figure output]